# PVCS checked out files to GIT

Tags: git, pvcs

I am trying to get files in PVCS to GIT repository , as I found out there seems to be no easy way to doing this

I have revision like so

File.cbs_rev_1

File.cbs_rev_1_0_2 excetra...

can I get all files along with their revision/version into GIT ??

Answer (score 0):

As this [paper describes](http://www.openmakesoftware.com/docs/ConvertingPVCStoGitorSubversion.pdf), make sure that your PVCS repo isn't too large for a git repo.

> It is a mistake to think of a PVCS conversion as only moving files and their revision history to Git or Subversion. The requirements for moving history, updating scripts, training and best practice approach should be well thought out to fit your specific conversion needs and needs of the developers who are impacted by the change.

I wouldn't try to get *all* the history for each file, but rather:

- check if that PVCS repo contains labels (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346807/6309)),
- display each tag in its local workspace
- import that as a single revision in a git repo (with the git-work-tree tip, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14192635/6309)).